# Exibindo data que um cookies expira em php

Tags: php, html, cookies

Atualmente eu seto meu cookie assim:

```
setcookie("visita","sim", time() + 172800,  $path = "/"); // 86400 = 1 dia, 172800 = 2 dias (SEGUNDOS)
```

Mas como posso mostrar em uma pagina php assim:

**Seu cookie "visita" expira em : 15/20/2050**

TIPO ISSO QUE O NAVEGADOR FAZ:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não há como obter essa informação, porque isso não é enviado para o servidor.

---

Quando o servidor envia um cookie para o usuário (SERVIDOR -> CLIENTE) é utilizado o cabeçalho de `Set-Cookie`, nele possui alguns parâmetros como [listados aqui](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2), o atributo de `expires` é um deles.

Entretanto, no oposto isso não é feito. Quando o cliente requisita o site ele utiliza o cabeçalho de `Cookie`, nele apenas contêm a informação do `nome` e `valor` do cookie, mas não os outros dados.

---

Portanto:

```
== Servidor -> Cliente ==

Set-Cookie: lang=en-US; Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT

== Cliente -> Servidor ==

Cookie: lang=en-US
```

> O PHP só tem a informação de `lang=en-US`, os dados de expiração o cliente não informa (já que este valor já foi informado pelo servidor num momento anterior).

---

Uma alternativa é incluir a data de "expiração" dentro do próprio cookie, ou armazenar o tempo de "expiração" quando usar o `Set-Cookie`.

Neste caso poderia utilizar:

```
$t = time() + 172800;
setcookie("visita", $t, $t,  $path = "/");
```

Dessa forma, quando usar o `$_COOKIE['visita']` terá o valor que é "o mesmo" do prazo de expiração.

Comment: Obrigado! tem como transformar o valor que aparece em data ?

Comment: Pode formatar usando o [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php).